# Error inicio del servidor de Ruby on Rails con 'rails s', en Linux Mint, por consola (Bundler Error Backtrace)

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lo que intento hacer es iniciar mi servidor de ruby on rails con `rails s`, pero en la consola de linux me aparecen los siguientes errores:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/ext/fixnum.rb:4: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.2/lib/concurrent/map.rb:206: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/digest_utils.rb:47: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/digest_utils.rb:51: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:110: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:111: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'autoprefixer-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-6.3.6.2/lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb:2:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-6.3.6.2/lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-6.3.6.2/lib/autoprefixer-rails.rb:35:in `require_relative'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-6.3.6.2/lib/autoprefixer-rails.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
/home/david/Escritorio/codigo_ticket/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
    from /home/david/Escritorio/codigo_ticket/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Ya instale `Ruby` y estoy usando la `version 2.4.0` y tambien instale `rails` y es la version `rails 5.0.0`, al tratar de verificar la version de rails con el comando `rails -v` sale lo siguiente:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/ext/fixnum.rb:4: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.2/lib/concurrent/map.rb:206: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
Rails 5.0.0
```

Comment: Creo que el error es otro, el warning del `Fixnum` y `Bignum` no es lo que impide que se ejecute tu servidor.

Comment: Puede ser que no tengas instalado un `runtime` para `JavaScript`? mira este parte del mensaje: `Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime`.

Comment: mira si tienes instalado NodeJS, asi Rails lo puede usar como runtime de JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error, tal como lo destaca Alejandro en los comentarios, se debe a que no tienes instalado *runtime* alguno para *JavaScript*; para resolver el problema simplemente instala uno, por ejemplo, **Node.js**<sup>1</sup>:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

<sup>1</sup> Si no deseas utilizar *Node.js*, puedes consultar otras opciones en la liga proporcionada por el mismo error: https://github.com/rails/execjs

Los *warnings* mostrados al inicio

```
warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
```

se deben al cambio que se hizo a partir de Ruby 2.4 para unificar las clases `Fiuxnum` y `Bignum` en `Integer` (más información [aquí](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/)); puedes ignorarlos, pero si quieres eliminarlos entonces actualiza tu versión de rails a **5.0.2**.